# Writing bas64 Callback response from Sencha to File.writer Phonegap issue

Tags: cordova, ios6, sencha-touch-2

i'm facing a pb about decoding a response.responseText from a Rest service (which job is to send me a cert.p12 file).

So i'm able to get my data in

```
var obj = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
```

then this data is a base64 object i want to decode and write my file.

i tried several javascript decoder with no luck, the cordova writer.write method don't work, while trying to write my file with no decoding method works (but is not a valid file).

Someone could help me finding a method to decode my file ?
here's my call to the rest service

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'https://certtest.idshost.fr/restgetcertificate.php',
            method: 'POST',
            withCredentials: false,
            useDefaultXhrHeader: false,

            params: Ext.JSON.encode(data),
            callback: function(options, success, response) {


                if (success) {
                    var obj = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                    localStorage.setItem('certif', obj.certbase64encoded);
                } else{
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Fail', 'marche pas');
                }
            }
        });
```

the File Api function

```
   toto:function(obj){

       console.log('entree toto');
       var ba64 =obj.certbase64encoded;
       var decode = decode64(ba64);
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 5*1204*1024, gotFS, fail);

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
       console.log("getfile");
        fileSystem.root.getFile("cert.p12", {create: true}, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }


    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
       console.log("create file");
        fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
    }

    function gotFileWriter(writer) {
        writer.write(decode);

    }




       }
    function fail(error) {
        console.log(error.code);
    }

       }
```

my decoder function

```
function decode64(input) {
  var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP" +
               "QRSTUVWXYZabcdef" +
               "ghijklmnopqrstuv" +
               "wxyz0123456789+/" +
               "=";
     var output = "";
     var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
     var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
     var i = 0;

     // remove all characters that are not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /, or =
     var base64test = /[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g;
     if (base64test.exec(input)) {
        alert("There were invalid base64 characters in the input text.\n" +
              "Valid base64 characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, '+', '/',and '='\n" +
              "Expect errors in decoding.");
     }
     input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

     do {
        enc1 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc2 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc3 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc4 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

        chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
        chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
        chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

        if (enc3 != 64) {
           output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
        }
        if (enc4 != 64) {
           output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
        }

        chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
        enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";

     } while (i < input.length);

     return unescape(output);
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried to dump the data to the console? Are you sure the base64 encoding is the failing bit? I would rather suspect there is an issue with the code writing out the file.

Comment: you're right is not the base64 decoding, but the file writer who don't handle binary.